# get Month start date and end date of all month passed between 2 Dates in python or Mysql

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Example: 
Start Date 20/01/2016
End Date   28/07/2016

Result Needed is:

1. 20/01/2016 -  31/01/2016
2. 01/02/2016 -  28/02/2016
3. 01/03/2016 -  31/03/2016
   .
   .
   .
4. 01/07/2016 -  28/07/2016

Comment: Look up using a calendar table in MySQL.

Comment: Please edit the question with the code you are trying to use to solve your problem and people here will point out the problems it has. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: I'm sure it's smarter to do this in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query**

```
SELECT @start := '2016-01-20', @end := '2016-07-28';

SELECT CONCAT(MIN(t.`Date`), ' - ', MAX(t.`Date`)) AS `Dates` FROM
  (SELECT ADDDATE(@start, INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY) AS `Date`
   FROM
     (SELECT a.a
      FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
         SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
      CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
         SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL 
         SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
      CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
         SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL
         SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c) a
   JOIN
     (SELECT @i := -1) r1
   WHERE @i < DATEDIFF(@end, @start) )t
GROUP BY MONTH(t.`Date`), YEAR(t.`Date`);
```

Comment: Incidentally, this gets you more rows in less typing... `SELECT i2.i*10+i1.i+1 i 
  FROM (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
        SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) i1
     , (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
        SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) i2 
 ORDER 
    BY i;`